# Reference of SVM Using Spark

Tags: apache-spark

Can somebody please give me some reference on implementing SVM using PySpark.

Comment: Hi Sean, I'm learning Spark and working on different methodologies. SVM is one of them. But when I was looking for some reference about it, I could not find anything relevant. So I put the question here.

Comment: Have you looks for the Spark official documentation? It contains concrete example about how to use SVM. You might also want to look at the pyspark api doc!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html#linear-support-vector-machines-svms) of Apache Spark's MLib library has a neat and clear reference to the implementation of linear SVM's in Python.

It supports two models: `SVMWithSGD` and `SVMModel`

Comment: Thanks Dawny! This link even though very brief, have been helpful.

Comment: @Beta Glad it helped!